# Entry (XAML Form) object reference null only with UWP App

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have a problem with an Entry object in my Xamarin.Forms App.

When I use the app on an Android device, there is no problem. I can enter a text in it and then use this text on a `ButtonPressed` event. But on UWP App I have a null reference on my `Entry` Object. Here you can find my code and the excpetion :

```
[using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace XamarinTest2.views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Search : ContentPage
    {
        public Search ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Vid.Text = "lol";
        }

        void SearchVideo(Object sender)
        {
            Application.Current.MainPage = new PageFeedYouTube(Vid.Text);
            //This line throws NullReferenceException on Vid
        }
```

And here my xaml view :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XamarinTest2.views.Search"
             Title="Recherche">    
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Recherche YouTube!"
                  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            <Entry Placeholder="Video" Text="" IsVisible="True" IsEnabled="True" IsPassword="True" x:Name="Vid"/>
            <Button Text="Recherche" Pressed="SearchVideo" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

I'm a little lost, why does my Entry doesn't work in my UWP App?

Comment: But when you set the `Text` `lol` in constructor `Vid` is not `null`?

Comment: Could you post the code how you navigate to the `Search` page? I have tested this on my PC and it works properly in UWP. Could you try creating a simple empty Xamarin.Forms project with just this page and test if this happens there?

Comment: Indeed in the constructor, Vid is not null. And ok i try from an empty project.

Comment: Very weird :-O . Let me know, this is a very interesting problem

Comment: Ok i have the same result even in an empty project. Here the code of my Main Menu : [link](https://github.com/MKostiuk/Xamarin_YT/blob/master/XamarinTest2/XamarinTest2/views/MainMenu.xaml.cs)

Comment: I will try the code when I get home in the evening

Comment: Thank you, i will search by my side and tell you if I find something.

Comment: Ok i just tried something else, instead of getting Entry i'm getting my label Text after having naming it with x:Name in xamk file. I'm still getting the error, the Label is null when i handle the Pressed Event,. I have also tested to handle TextChangedEvent and in this case i can get the correct entered text. It's like when i Press the button all the View is reinitialized.

Comment: I completely forgot about this thread, thank you for the notification. I will look at it today, writing a notification in calendar 

Comment: I have taken a look at your code and it is super unusual, the same thing works normally but does not in your case. I am able to replicate it in your project, but it works normally in an empty solution 

Comment: Really? Did I miss something? It doesn't work for me in an empty solution so it's maybe a local problem. Do you think you can send me your empty solution so I can check?

Comment: Actually the only difference between my code and yours is the `RoundedButton` - I have used regular `Button` and `OnClicked` event instead. Try it to see if it works. Then the problem must be with `RoundedButton`

Comment: I already have because when i first met this problem (my solution evolved and i test it on Android) i didn't have added RoundedButton like in my correctionEntry branch in which i tried the other solution bellow. I try again in an empty solution.

Comment: I finally got it!!! See the answer :-) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I know where the problem is! It was **hidden in plain sight** all the time.

See the `SearchVideo` method signature:

```
void SearchVideo(object sender);
```

And now the `Pressed` event signature:

```
void Pressed(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

You probably see it too now, right  ? The catch is that the **signature** of your method **differs** from what the event expects. For some reason this throws off the XAML parser and breaks the `x:Name` bindings while still being able to compile however!

So to fix the issue the only change you need is to add the `EventArgs` parameter:

```
private void SearchVideo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ResultPage = new PageFeedYouTube(Vid.Text);
    Navigation.PushAsync(ResultPage);
}
```

I'm still smiling of how sneaky this bug was. Oh well, developers learn something new every day  .

Comment: Wow ok! Thank you very much, it was driven me crazy! But why does it pass on Android? From now I will always check signatures in the official documentation.

Comment: I am really not sure why it does work on Android, and I suspect the reason will be somewhere deep inside the framework itself. But at least we solved it :-D ! Just as a tip - when you type the event attribute in XAML (like `Pressed="`) Intellisense should offer you to create the event handler method automatically. You can let it do its magic and then just rename the method to match your needs (in both code and XAML). This way you will surely have the right signature.

Answer (score 0):

Give your button an `x:Name` like `<Button Text="Recherche" x:Name="RechercheBtn" />`.

Now, in your code, add a command to that button like so:

```
public Search ()
{ 
    InitizializeComponent();
    Vid.Text= "lol";
    RechercheBtn.Command = new Command(() => SearchVideo(Vid.Text));
}
```

Then, modify your `SearchVideo` Function as such:

```
void SearchVideo(string vidText)
{
    Application.Current.MainPage = new PageFeedYouTube(vidText); 
}
```

Comment: Ok I have tested your solution. Now the search is done but with an Empty String, and if i try to read this String i still get the same Exception.